# How to make Chunk underline or bold to display in a pdf

Tags: itext

I've been wracking my brain for a couple of days and I am unable to get this working. I am trying to use itextsharp in vb.net and MVC to format a field with bold or underline and  then see those changes in the resulting PDF. I am not getting errors but nothing I do changes the fields. The PDF loads fine but the formatting of the fields never changes.

I am trying to convert the text into a pdf paragraph, then loop through its chunks and apply formatting. Then I would like to use "SetField" to fill the field with the resulting string. 
Something like:

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetField(fieldName, formattedString)
```

I am  new to this so I am not sure where to troubleshoot further. I have also tried creating a new font and adding that and the document remains unchanged.

I can't upload the PDF file for inspection, but if there is something I should check in the PDF file that might cause this please let me know. The file is in XFA format.

I  have the pseudo-code below:

1. The code that calls the GenerateDocument function:

   ```
   Dim pdf As Byte()
   pdf = GenerateDocument()
   Return File(pdf, "application/pdf")
   ```
2. The GenerateDocument function(simplified):

   ```
   Public Function GenerateDocument() As Byte()
    Using inStream As New MemoryStream(TemplateBinary) 'the actual pdf binary
     Using outStream As New MemoryStream

      Dim pdfReader As New text.pdf.PdfReader(inStream)
      Dim stamper As New PdfStamper(pdfReader, outStream)
      Dim form As AcroFields = stamper.AcroFields
      Dim fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys

      stamper.AddViewerPreference(PdfName.HIDETOOLBAR, New PdfBoolean(True))
      stamper.AddViewerPreference(PdfName.FITWINDOW, New PdfBoolean(True))
      stamper.FormFlattening = False

      Dim pdfSegment As Paragraph = CreateSimpleHtmlParagraph("sample text")
      Dim pdfString As New StringBuilder

      If pdfSegment.Count > 0 Then
        For counter As Integer = 0 To pdfSegment.Count - 1

         Dim para As Paragraph

         If pdfSegment(counter).GetType().Name().ToUpper().Contains("PARAGRAPH") Then
           para = pdfSegment(counter)
           For Each ch As Chunk In para
            ch.SetUnderline(0.5F, -1.5F) 'just make everything underline for now
           Next
           pdfString.Append(para.Content)
         End If

         If counter < (pdfSegment.Count - 1) Then
          pdfString.AppendLine()
         End If
        Next

        form.SetField(xNode.Name, pdfString.ToString())
     End If
     stamper.Close()
     pdfReader.Close()
     Return outStream.ToArray()

    End Using
    End Using
   End Function
   ```
3. The code that makes a PDF paragraph called from the code above

   ```
   Private Function CreateSimpleHtmlParagraph(text As String) As Paragraph
   Dim pdfTextSection As New Paragraph()

   Using sr As StringReader = New StringReader(text)
   Dim elements As List(Of IElement) = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, Nothing)

   For Each e As IElement In elements
    pdfTextSection.Add(e)
   Next
   End Using

   Return pdfTextSection
   ```

   End Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code listed under 2 is very strange. You create a `Paragraph` object which consists of some plain text, a font, leading info, indentation info, etc... Then you ask the `Paragraph` for the plain text *without* the font info. Elementary logic tells you that the general `StringBuilder` class is unaware of iTextSharp-specific concepts such as `Chunk`, `Font` and underline.

You are also assuming that an ordinary text field is capable of containing rich text. Ordinary text fields are usually defined to contain text in one single font. For instance: "Helvetica" for regular text. Or "Helvetica Bold" for bold text. "Helvetica" and "Helvetica Bold" are two *different* fonts (of the *same* family). It is important not to confuse the concept *font* with the concept *font family*.

"Underline" is not a quality of the font. Ordinary text fields can't be defined as "the value needs to be underlined".

This means that you'll need a work-around to achieve what you need. This workaround is described in my book, more specifically where I explain the [MovieAds](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=163) example (look [here](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C08) if you need the C# version).

In this example, I don't use the `setField()` method because of the limitations of ordinary text fields. Instead, I get the position of the field and I add the rich text using the `ColumnText` object:

```
AcroFields.FieldPosition f = form.GetFieldPositions(fieldname)[0];
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(
  f.position.Left, f.position.GetBottom(2),
  f.position.GetRight(2), f.position.Top
);
ct.AddElement(para);
ct.Go();
```

Comment: The reason I use setField() is because I need to load string values obtained from a database into each field on the PDF template. I also tried SetFieldProperty to change formatting and the formatting remained unchanged. Forgive me for omitting this info but I tried to keep the question small and I didn't think it was important at the time. So basically, I need to get a string value, check it for underline or bold formatting, and then load the field on the template with the string value and ensure the formatting appears. Do  you have an example of something like this? And thanks for the help.

Comment: My answer offer an alternative to using `setField()`. You ignore the fact that *underline* can't be defined for a field in PDF (hence `setField()` can't be used and you *need* to use the alternative). You're asking for an example while I have already given you an example that does exactly what you need. It's as if you don't want to be helped...

Comment: I didn't ignore your advice, I am going to try it when I get to the office. And I asked about using SetField because I am a beginner with this material and I don't know what is possible yet.

Comment: OK. SetField() works when you use forms with ordinary text fields the way it's described in ISO-32000-1. You're trying to do something different,  hence you need a different approach.

Comment: Your code works well when I need to apply formatting. For my application, some fields don't need it so I determine which ones need the formatting and use your code for those fields and the ones that only need to be loaded are done so with SetField(). Thanks